# In a correctly modeled CQRS domain, can a single command have multiple events?

Tags: cqrs

Are there scenarios where a single command results in having multiple events in CQRS? Can anybody give an example for this?

I'm asking because aggregates are transactional boundaries, and the implementation of writing an aggregate depends on the answer to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, for example consider the command AssignUserToGroup. The domain logic checks if some groups the user belongs to are mutually exclusive with the new one and if so 2 events are published: UserLeftTheGroup and UserEnteredTheGroup.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great example I can use as a base for discussion with my co-workers :-)!

Comment: What if the mutually exclusive rule  is managed by a process manager? Is it a matter of lines of code or conceptually it can be possible to have a command that produce two events?

Comment: In that case, I would like to simplify the domain even more. For example: the "AddUserToGroup" command won't publish any event if the user belongs to another mutually exclusive group. The Actor has to issue a "RemoveUserFromGroup" command which would publish "UserLeftGroup" event. Then the Actor again has to issue "AddUserToGroup" which will publish "UserEnteredGroup" event making the user become part of the new group.

Comment: In my opinion, command (in this case "AddUserToGroup") and also the Aggregate operation should not take any implicit/hidden decision.This kills the benefit of ubiquitous language. Aggregate boundary must be limited to only one and one operation.

Comment: @Arindam How interaction should happen through UI. Does it have to make multiple network calls to achieve results??